# Strange behaviour with FILTER on dynamic array in MS Excel

Tags: excel, filter, array-formulas, dynamic-arrays

On an Excel sheet, please put these functions into the cells indicated:

- A1:  `=RANDARRAY(10,3,1,20,TRUE)`
- E1:  `=FILTER(A1#,$B$1:$B$10>12)`
- I1: `=FILTER(INDEX(A1#,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1#)),{1,3}),$B$1:$B$10>12)`
- L1: `=INDEX(A1#,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1#)),{1,3})`

Now hit your Function-9 key to generate new random numbers in the dynamic array anchored to cell A1.  Most of the time everything works as expected, but now and then you get a `#SPILL` error in **E1** or in **I1** or in both (never in **L1**).  The error message that appears when you hover over the little yellow triangle beside the `#SPILL` error says '*We can't tell how many rows and columns to spill into.*'

What is causing this bizarre behaviour, and can I make it go away?
I’m using Excel version 2210 (Build 15726.20262)

Comment: It is because `RandArray` is volatile. [spill error docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-spill-error-ffe0f555-b479-4a17-a6e2-ef9cc9ad4023)

Comment: Ah...thanks.  It's because the volatile array is changing between calculations.  Makes sense.